# ds18b20 temperature sensor and arduino

Tags: arduino, sensors, temperature

I am currently writing this simple code to check the temp sensor

```
#include <One Wire . h>

int DS18S20_Pin = 2; //DS18S20 Signal pin on digital 2

//Temperature chip i/o
OneWire ds(DS18S20_Pin); // on digital pin 2

void setup(void) {
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(void) 
{
 float temperature = getTemp();
 Serial.println(temperature);

 delay(100); //just here to slow down the output so it is easier to read

}
```

I m getting "sketch_feb27a:14: error: 'getTemp' was not declared in this scope"
can someone tell me why?

Comment: is getTemp() a library function ?? have you included it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here your trying call **getTemp();** . But below function is not defined under sketch itself..if you add the activity related to **getTemp();** it must work.

```
float temperature = getTemp();
```

Answer (score 1):

Either you have not extracted the OneWire library to the correct location, or have made a mistake in the #include line.
Include it without spaces

```
*include<OneWire.h>
```

If getTemp() is not a part of the library OneWire then obviously you have to make your own getTemp() function

Answer (score 0):

You can use DallasTemperature library.

Use it like this:

```
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

// Data wire is plugged into port 2 on the Arduino
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 2

OneWire dsOneWire(DS_ONE_WIRE_BUS);

// Pass our oneWire reference to Dallas Temperature.
DallasTemperature dsSensorControler(&dsOneWire);

dsSensorControler.begin();

dsSensorControler.requestTemperatures();

float temp = dsSensorControler.getTempCByIndex(0);
```

Code from [DallasTemperature library](http://milesburton.com/index.php?title=Dallas_Temperature_Control_Library) sample.